# How to test value changes from a subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

A component does an API call which then changes a variable, like:

```
postStuff() {
  this.apiService.postStuff(whatever).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.variable = true; // was previously false
  });
}
```

Now I want to write a test that checks if apiService.postStuff() was called and this.variable ends up as true.

```
it('should ...', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(apiService, 'postStuff').and.callThrough();
  component.postStuff();
  expect(apiService.postStuff).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Works
  // tick(); // Does not seem to help
  expect(component.variable).toBeTrue(); // Does not work. Says it's still false 
});
```

What is missing? Thanks.

Comment: you only provided a success callback for your subscribe method, the http call may fail and only the second callback of subscribe is invoked. I think a good option would be to mock the apiService because otherwise your tests will have side-effects to api's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to `callThrough()` in this scenario. Try removing `and.callThrough()` and using `.and.returnValue(of(true))` instead.

Lastly, the `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` may be extraneous since the above suggestion returns an observable value.

Comment: Yes, callThrough() was the problem, thanks,